# SPRING BOOT UPGRADE CAUSES ISSUE WITH REACTOR DEPENDENCIES

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have the updated my application spring and spring boot dependencies to the following version.

```
   spring-version-5.3.18.   spring-boot-version-2.5.12
```

Not sure why the reactor related dependencies are breaking  and i get this while starting  up the application

> ```
> ***************************
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
>
>     org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.netty.NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.createHttpServer(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.java:163)
>
> The following method did not exist:
>
>     reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer.runOn(Lreactor/netty/resources/LoopResources;)Lreactor/netty/transport/Transport;
>
> The method's class, reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer, is available from the following locations:
>
>     jar:file:/Users/vn50y2z/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty/0.9.11.RELEASE/reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar!/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.class
>     jar:file:/Users/vn50y2z/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty-http/1.0.17/reactor-netty-http-1.0.17.jar!/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.class
>
> The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
>
>     reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer: file:/Users/vn50y2z/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty/0.9.11.RELEASE/reactor-netty-0.9.11.RELEASE.jar
>
>
> Action:
>
> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer
> ```

Comment: Fix your all-caps.

Comment: It will be hard to know specifically what is wrong without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)- specifically, a POM that results in this error. But a first guess is that you've overridden the Spring Boot-provided version of `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` with an incompatible one.

Comment: If you are manually managing both Spring and Spring Boot you are already doing it wrong. Which makes me worry for all your other dependencies. Please add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file to the question.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: resolved after updating  the right versions in dependency management and remove the conflicting dependencies